# Call registerForActivityResult from non-Fragment/Activity class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I want to call `registerForActivityResult` from a Java class other than my `Fragment`. Is it possible to do that?

Here you can see an example of what I mean:

```
public class Hello
{
    private ActivityResultLauncher<String[]> mMultipleActivityResultLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions(), isGranted ->{
            
        });
}
```

Comment: `registerForActivityResult` is a method on the `Activity` class, so if you want to do this you have to pass in an activity instance to your `Hello` class to call that on.

Comment: @TylerV the problem is that I am calling the given class from a fragment. If you know how to solve this problem, could you show me an example?

Comment: Every fragment lives within an activity, which you can get using `getActivity()`, or you can just use the Fragment like the answer below. Be careful not to leak a context though.

Comment: @TylerV I have added my code, please take a look, because I am still having problems.

Comment: Your fragment is null until after the constructor, you can't call the register method on it inline like the answer below showed or it will be null

Comment: When u pass activity instance make sure it is a sub class instance of ComponentActivity otherwise it won't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the `Activity`/`Fragment` instance to the class, and call `registerForActivityResult` on that.

For example, based on your code (for an `Activity`, just replace all the instances of `Fragment` with `Activity`):

```java
public class Hello {
    private Fragment fragment;
    private ActivityResultLauncher<String[]> mMultipleActivityResultLauncher;

    public Hello(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.mMultipleActivityResultLauncher = fragment.registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions(), isGranted -> {

        });
    }
}
```